# WS2012, VSS Backup errors

Tags: backup, vss

I have few problems with VSS Full Backup on WS 2012 R2.

I have 3 physical servers with few VM's on each. I'm doing Full Backup everyday via Windows Server backup. On each server I have different error.

1. I have here 8 VM's (6 are Online all the time, and 2 are currently offline). It completes backup for 5Online VM's + 2 Offline, but it says that one VM's backup failed because it was offline (which it wasn't cause it has uptime like 30days+ and I'm using it all the time). There is no info about it, just Event ID 519 in event viewer that says backup has failed for that voulme.
2. 4 VM's here, 2 Online 2 Offline, backup failed for one offline VM (which is currently offline), but at the other offline it completed backup normally.
3. 5 Online VM's - all completed successfully.

Now, on every VM I have checked backup in Integration Services. I'm doing full backup once a day, it is backup to a volume (each physical server has added space via iSCSI.

Any idea?
Best regards

Comment: 1. vssadmin list writers - run that as admin on system, and check on each writer does it have errors. If yes then there's no other option then restart of machine. A lot of people already try to bypass this but it's impossible to clear cache of VSS. Unless you are not using VSS.
2. why on earth you are doing full backup daily? are you using bare system backup or have some backup software implemented? 3. Even with system free one you can still do better - resource wise I mean. Like 1 time full + 5 inc....